# How to perform group by operation in dataTable using multiple columns dynamically in c#?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to group columns using linq dynamically i.e. user will select table and columns at runtime.

[image]

Ex: The above table has Territory,

State, BankName,

Assume user has selected these columns for grouping (Territory,Bank Name)

How can use linq to do this?

Comment: Dynamic `OrderBy` is not trivial: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet With classic ( weakly typed ) methods: `DataView dv = new DataView(table);
        dv.Sort = "State, BankName ASC";`

Comment: There exists something called `DynamicQuery`, I'm nore sure about Grouping, but dynamic sorting works pretty well. https://www.nuget.org/packages/DynamicQuery

Answer (score 1):

you may want to use [System.Linq.Dynamic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic)

```
var fields = new List<string>() { "Territory", "Bank Name"};
var qfields = string.Join(", ", fields.Select(x => "it[\"" + x + "\"] as " + x));

var q = dt
    .AsEnumerable()
    .AsQueryable()
    .GroupBy("new(" + qfields + ")", "it")
    .Select("new (it as Data)");
foreach (dynamic d in q)
{
    foreach (var row in d.Data)
    {
       // Do your work here, using d.Territory
    }  
}
```

Check this post [Split a Datatable into multiple Datatables based on a list of column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18030415/split-a-datatable-into-multiple-datatables-based-on-a-list-of-column-names/18032247#18032247)