# How to perform Sum of a column dynamically in C#?

Tags: c#, linq

I am using System.Linq.Dynamic to group columns using linq dynamically and need to perform

How can I SUM a column i.e.(Sum(Deposits)). User will select table and columns at runtime. 
[image]
Ex: The above table has Territory, State, BankName, Year, QuarterFromMainT

Assume user has selected these columns for grouping (Territory, State, BankName) and Now wants to sum a Column ex:Deposits. How can I do this? Because only ASEnumerable and AsQueryable only has sum. We need to perform groupby and sum

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059659/how-to-perform-group-by-operation-in-datatable-using-multiple-columns-dynamicall) for further clarification and My Code is:

[image]

here t1 is table and qfields is a list which contains grouping columns.

How can use linq to Sum a column after groupby?

Comment: Possible duplicate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61870/sum-of-items-in-a-collection

Comment: Of course this is not my business, but I feel it's right thing to warn you and ask: did you post sensitive data? If yes - your employer/customer won't be happy.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?  If not, please disregard...

```
var query = rows
    .GroupBy(row => new { row.Territory, row.State, row.BankName })
    .Select(group => new
    {
        group.Key.Territory, group.Key.State, group.Key.BankName,
        Deposits = group.Sum(row => row.Deposits)
    });
```

Comment: How can i do the sum?

Comment: The query has dynamic columns not static i.e. user will select table and columns to groupby and column to sum at runtime. How can I perform this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to Set Footer Text to display your sum amount

Example:

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Deposits" 
             FooterText="Total Desposits" />
```

and in Gridview you need to  write coding like this

```
 Gridview.Columns[4].FooterText = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<int>("Desposits")).Sum().ToString();

        Gridview.DataSource = dt;

        Gridview.DataBind();
```

its working in my application. you can use it according to your convenient.